# Libreoffice display incorrect integral sign of doc file

Tags: formula, equation, libreoffice

I have a .doc file include math equation and open by Libreoffice 5.0 in Ubuntu 16.04 but some equation (integral sign) display incorrect:

Incorrect display integral sign:

[image: (Picture 1) incorrect display integral sign]

Incorrect display other equation

[image: (Picture 2) incorrect display other equation]

I also open by Libreoffice 5.0 in Windows 10, it worked correctly. 
I also copy all font from Windows 10 to /usr/share/fonts/FontsWindows in Linux

Could you please help me to find any solution for that. 
Thank you so much for your support.

Answer (score 0):

Do your new fonts show up on the system?

Eg

```
fc-list
```

If not

```
sudo fc-cache -fv
```

OR

```
sudo fc-cache -fv <new font dir>
```

Also check your

```
~/.fonts.conf
```

All the best